# General system exception happened - The custom_range value wasn't found in the algorithms

Tags: magento2, attributes, product-attribute, csv, exception

When importing a csv spreadsheet I am getting the following error:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In `vendor/magento/module-import-export/Model/Export/AbstractEntity.php`

You will find

```
/**
 * Limit of errors after which pre-processing will exit
 *
 * @var int
 */
protected $_errorsLimit = 100;
```

It's probably the limit that makes you getting that message.

That being said if you want to know what is wrong you probably have more details in `var/log/system.log` and `var/log/exception.log`

Comment: [2022-03-09 15:42:23] report.CRITICAL: The custom_range value wasn't found in the algorithms. {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\LocalizedException(code: 0): The custom_range value wasn't found in the algorithms. at /app/*/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/Dynamic/AlgorithmFactory.php:74)"} []

Comment: magento seems ot tell you that you are trying to search or filter with a custom_range algorithm type but that algorithm type does not exist. It might  be a configuration issue, check : `catalog/layered_navigation/price_range_calculation`

Comment: I've already tried changing Stores > Settings > Configuration > Catalog > Layered Navigation > Price Navigation Step Calculation. But I didn't get the expected result.